# I cant find the solutin can pls someone

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am doing a Note app but my problem ist that

```
var id: Int? = 0

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle? ) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

  addbt.setOnClickListener {
    var dbManger = DbManger(this!!.requireContext())
    val title = ettittel.text.toString()
    val beschreibung = etbeschreibung.text.toString()
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put("Title", title)
    values.put("Beschreibung", beschreibung)

    if (id == 0) {
      val id = dbManger.insertNotiz(values)
      if (id > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Text wurde hinzugefügt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Fehlgeschlagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
    } else {
      val selectionArgs = arrayOf(id.toString())
      val id = dbManger.update(values, "ID=?", selectionArgs)
      if (id > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Text wurde geändert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "änderung Fehlgeschlagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
    }
  }

  setHasOptionsMenu(true)
  val id = arguments?.getInt("ID")
  
  if (id != 0) {
    val Title = arguments?.getString("Title")
    ettittel.setText(Title)
    val beschreibung = arguments?.getString("Beschreibung")
    etbeschreibung.setText(beschreibung)
  }

}
```

the error is that it never jumps in the else loop so when i want to edit the text it adds the new text every time i try for hours but i couldn't get it i will be very happy about a helpful tip
thank you very much in advance

Comment: `arguments?.getInt("ID")` Are you getting correct value here?

Comment: And update the title of the question so that it describes the exact problem you are facing instead of putting a general "Help me" statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `id` property

```
var id: Int? = 0
```

But when you retrieve the id from arguments, you assign it to a local variable

```
val id = arguments?.getInt("ID")
```

And your `id` property remains unmodified, i.e. equals to 0. To fix this issue you should change the previous line of code to this

```
id = arguments?.getInt("ID")
```

Comment: i do it but it still the same wrong i can edit the text but when i want to add a new text he dont go to the another loop he give me the text from the else loop